# Different floating point matrix multiplication result on two GPUs

Tags: floating-point, gpu, metal

I am running a `MPSMatrixMultiplication` from Metal Performance Shader on two separate GPUs, one is internal GPU and one is AMD GPU. The matrices are exactly the same.

But the problem is that the result is not exactly the same. I know there is some precision loss on GPU, but why the results are not the same with the same IEEE 754-2008 standard?

I want to verify the correctness of a GPU calculation. How could I do that? Should I allow 0.0001 difference, which is the maximum difference between each result?

Comment: Are the two devices using the same floating-point formats? Do they both conform to IEEE-754? Are the processes performing the matrix multiplications doing exactly the same operations in exactly the same order? The latter is quite likely not the case. The multiplication may be broken up into subtasks that are dispatched to available processors, and the partitioning may vary depending on hardware characteristics, and the recombination of results may depend on when various processors complete their tasks.

Comment: How much variation there may be depends on the condition number of the matrix (which is data dependent), the algorithms used, and more. If you want to test a GPU computation, rather than test the results for a particular matrix, then you can use prepared simple matrices with good numerical properties. E.g., you can use matrices with most elements zero and a few non-zero (and simple values, like small integers), then perform repeated tests with different non-zero elements, testing the entire multiplication over multiple sets of tests.

Answer (score 1):

The Metal compiler uses `fast-math` by default, which enables the GPU to violate IEEE 754 to increase performance. I guess this is the reason why you are getting different results.

You should be able to disable `fast-math` in your project's build settings.

Comment: I did set the MTL_FAST_MATH to NO, but the results are still different... I am using 32-bit floating point number, and I am guessing if the Intel GPU supports it

Comment: Have you tried add the option `-fno-fast-math` to the `MTL_COMPILER_FLAGS` (Other Metal Compiler Flags) instead of setting the flag?

Comment: I didn't see that option in my Building Settings. Should I add a user-defined setting by clicking the plus sign? I tried to added one but still doesn't work.